# Heapsort implementation in C - array error

Tags: c, sorting, heapsort

I was trying to implement Heapsort algorithm in C but I'm not sure I'm done it right. I also have an error "variably modified 'A' at file scope". I was searching similar topic on stackoverflow and I found out that heapSize should be const but then I couldn't use it as a variable in my functions. What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int heapSize = 100;
int length;
int A[heapSize];

int Heapify(int i) {
  int l = 2*i;
  int r = 2*i + 1;
  int largest;
  int tmp;

  if( l <= heapSize && A[l] > A[i]) largest = l;
  else largest = i;

  if (r <= heapSize && A[r] > A[largest]) largest = r;

  if (largest != i) {
    tmp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[largest];
    A[largest] = tmp;
    }
}

int BuildHeap() {
  heapSize = length;
  int i;

  for (i = floor(length/2); i <= 1; i--) {
    Heapify(i);
    }
}

int main(void) {
  int i,tmp;

  BuildHeap();

  for (i = length; i <= 2; i--) {
    tmp = A[heapSize];
    A[heapSize] = A[1];
    A[1] = A[heapSize];

    heapSize = heapSize - 1;

    Heapify(1);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I changed the first part of program to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 100


int heapSize = 10;
int A[LENGTH]
```

and, based on your suggestions, replace the "floor(length/2)" to "LENGTH/2". I solve my problems with compiling but I'm pretty sure this implementation is just bad. Well, anyway thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You should make `heapSize` a `const int`, and use local variables to do the work.

Comment: I don't understand. If I'll make heapSize a const, which means I can't change it later, how this algorithm will work? And then why should I use heapsize at all? Wouldn't be better to declare int A[100] for example?

Comment: It would be better to use a global length and a global pointer, and dynamically allocate whatever space you need.

Comment: Does `length` ever change? Also, you don't need to do `floor(i/2)` like in Javascript when you use integers: integer division truncates, so `i / 2` is enough.

Comment: Thank you, I cut out the floor part. And no, length does not change... and I'm a little confused by it. Well, I guess I'm really bad at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of issues with your code.

First, you declare a global `int length` variable, but you never assign it any value. So the `length` is always ZERO.

In `BuildHeap()` you do:

```
    for (i = floor(length/2); i <= 1; i--) ...
```

which starts with `floor(0/2)` that is with `i==0`. That value is less than `1` so the loop makes the first iteration and *decrements* `i` with the `i--` expression — and `i` becomes **minus one**. Then the loop proceeds until the `i` value wraps over zero to become positive (and greater than `1`). For 32-bit integers it would take about 2.14 billion iterations...

The very first thing your `main()` does is invoking `BuildHeap()` which in turn invokes (multiple times) `Heapify()`. The latter compares array items to decide if they should get swapped – but they were not assigned any values! You never fill the `A` array with any data...

Did you notice that you compare and swap items which are **outside** your `A` array (actually, **before** it), since `BuildHeap()` decrements `i` below zero and passes negatve index values to `Heapify()`...?

Your `Heapify` routine performs at most one swap in the array. It doesn't seem sufficient. Suppose the heap is already 3 levels deep, and the current item appears the smallest one in the heap; it should go to the deepest level, but how do you achieve that? A single swap moves the item just one level downwards.

---

This is how you could do it.

First, decide the maximum size of data you will handle and prepare the array:

```
#define LENGTH 100

int A[LENGTH + 1];
```

(You need 'plus one' because `A[0]` will not be a part of the heap — why?)

Then prepare variables to store an actual size of data:

```
int dataSize;
int heapSize;
```

and a routine to fill the array. You can read the user input or load data from a file, or just fill the array by some algorithm.

```
void FillArrayAscending() {
    dataSize = 16;
    for(int i = 1; i <= dataSize; i ++)
        A[i] = i;
}
void FillArrayDescending() {
    dataSize = 25;
    for(int i = 1; i <= dataSize; i ++)
        A[i] = 50 - i;
}
void FillArrayCrossed() {
    dataSize = 20;
    for(int i = 1; i <= dataSize; i += 2)
        A[i] = 10 + i;
    for(int i = 2; i <= dataSize; i += 2)
        A[i] = 30 - i;
}
```

Then you can 'heapify'. To do that you sift the item down the heap – you *iterate* swapping until the item reaches its place:

```
void SiftDown(int i) {
    while(i < heapSize) {
        int largest = i;

        if(2*i <= heapSize && A[i] < A[2*i])
            largest = 2*i;
        if(2*i + 1 <= heapSize && A[largest] < A[2*i + 1])
            largest = 2*i + 1;

        if(largest == i)
            break;  // the item reached its place

        A[0] = A[largest];
        A[largest] = A[i];
        A[i] = A[0];
        i = largest;  // new position to sift down...
    }
}
```

`i` indicates the item to be sifted down, `largest` denotes a swap destination, `A[0]` can be used as a temporary storage (why?).

Now you can build a heap in the array:

```
void BuildHeap() {
    heapSize = dataSize;
    for(int i = heapSize/2; i >= 1; i --)
        SiftDown(i);
}
```

and retrieve items from a heap in a descending order:

```
void ExtractHeap() {
    while(heapSize > 1) {
        A[0] = A[1];        // take the max item from a heap
        A[1] = A[heapSize]; // replace it with the last one
        A[heapSize] = A[0]; // add the max one to the sorted part
        heapSize --;
        SiftDown(1);        // re-heapify
    }
}
```

Now you can do the whole processing:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    FillArrayAscending();  // or Descending or...
    BuildHeap();
    ExtractHeap();

    // and here you can print the array contents
    // for indices 1 .. dataSize
    // to verify it is actually sorted
}
```

Comment: I am very thankful for your comprehensive answer. It really help me to understand my problems. Thank you once again!